# Login validation through url in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've one web application.from that i want to access my apex report instance.
so i place hyper link in application like

```
<a href="http://localhost:8100/apex/f?p=100:101:0:BRANCH_TO_PAGE_ACCEPT:::P101_USERNAME,P101_PASSWORD:example,Letmein+1">My Application</a>
```

even though i've pass the correct username and pwd.apex application throws the invalid password error.

kindly give solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the password `Letmein 1` (i.e. there is a space between `n` and `1`)?

If it's actually a `+`, your problem is that URL encoding treats `+` as a  (space) character. In which case you need to encode a literal `+`, e.g.

```
Letmein%2B1
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Ignoring the (most probably) terrible idea of hardcoding a password in a URL link...